# AZ extension botservice not found

Tags: azure, botframework, bots, azure-cli

I'm trying to create a new bot using the v4 bot framework. For that I'm following the enterprise bot template: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-enterprise-template-overview?view=azure-bot-service-4.0. In the readme it says I should run `az extension add -n botservice`. When I run this, I get an error that the extension 'botservice' can't be found. How do I solve this?

Comment: When you want to add the extension, you'd better list the available extension with the CLI command `az extension list-avaiable` first. And the extensions are different with the different Azure CLI version.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation hasn't been updated yet. The current version of azure-cli (2.0.53) ships with botservice as a core module. Azure CLI 2.0.53 does not use the botservice extension. Run

```
az extension remove -n botservice
```

and then try to continue the steps of the tutorial from there.

Comment: Unfortunately it says "The extension botservice is not installed.". I need to remove/upgrade it however, because when I want to run `msbot clone service` I get the following error: `You need to upgrade your az botservice version to >= 0.4.3.
To do this run:
   az extension remove -n botservice
   az extension add -n botservice`